# Kill background processes in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, concurrency, process, kill-process

I'm trying to build a start script and a stop script for my project. I need to run a sass auto-compiler as well as a server, and redirect the output of both to a file. I'm using `lite-server` and `sass --watch` for this.

To make these processes run concurrently, I'm using `&` to background the processes. This poses the challenge of stopping the scripts, I can't stop the scripts using `Ctrl+C` as I normally would. I thought I would overcome this by storing the process IDs in a text file.

I came up with the following "start" script:

```
# Start a sass watcher and a server running simultaneously. Store the PIDs in a
# text file so that the processes can be easily stopped.

(
  lite-server &
  echo $! > .pids.txt &
  sass --watch sass:css --style=compressed &
  echo $! >> .pids.txt &
) &> log.txt
cat .pids.txt
```

Then, to stop the processes, I'm using

```
kill $(cat .pids.txt)
```

Writing the process IDs to a text file seems kind of hackish. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Without writing the PIDs to text file, if these processes are bound to run only once (one instance) in your machine, you could use `killall` command. `killall -s KILL lite-server sass` (either individually or combined)

Comment: Ok, cool. I didn't think that would be best practice, but it makes sense.

Comment: @LukeTaylor I liked your approach with writing a file, since you can access it from other shell environments. Specifically, when using SSH for a remote connection. I don't know of a graceful way to group all the sub-processes and only kill that process. Did you have any luck with finding something mainstream?

Comment: Oh I found a good answer here: [Run multiple commands and kill them as one in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204721/359712) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store them in an array, if that's what you wouldn't call hackish.

**EDIT:**
Another way is to just execute:

```
kill $(jobs -p)
```

This kills all background processes (jobs -p prints the PIDs of all background process to stdout, which are then handed to kill).

Comment: Since I'm someone who knows next to nothing about bash, could you provide an example?

Comment: Sadly I'm also someone who knows next to nothing about bash, I only know one can use arrays in bash but never did myself. The bash reference on arrays ( https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays ) seems to indicate, that the use of arrays is very easy.
You can just introduce a index variable and increment it everytime you stored something in the array:
`((i++)); echo $! > array[i]
To kill all the processes with the ids in the array, you could use a for-loop where you decrement i until it's zero again and issue a kill on every pid found.
Please note I didn't test that code.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll check that out

Answer (score 4):

I may prefer to grep for the process and kill the process instead keeping the PIDs in a file.

```
ps -ef | grep lite-server | awk '{print $2}' | kill -9
```

I assume second column in output of `ps -ef`  is PID of the process `lite-server` in your server.

Comment: I'll try to fix your solution using `xargs`:
```bash
ps -ef | grep lite-server | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add what kind of "kill" you want..
such as: `kill -9 $(cat .pids.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

I found [Run multiple commands and kill them as one in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204721/359712), and the more detailed [How to Create a Process Group in Linux and Kill All Its Children](https://webhostinghero.org/how-to-create-a-process-group-in-linux/).

#### In short:

```bash
setsid sh -c 'command1 & command2 & command3 & wait'
process_group_id=$!

# and/or save to a file like '.pgid'
echo $process_group_id > .pgid

# to kill everything in that process group (mind the dash):

kill -TERM -$process_group_id
```

#### Note

Killing with `kill $process_group_id` will **NOT** kill the entire group! There *must* be a preceding `-` when killing an entire process group by id.

Also, you should pass the appropriate *signal* using `kill`. To print all the signals, run:

```bash
kill -l
1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGUSR2     13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD     18) SIGCONT     19) SIGSTOP     20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGURG      24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO       30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS      34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

So a forced kill would be:

```bash
kill -9 -$process_group_id
# OR
kill -SIGKILL -$process_group_id
```

But if the commands have a way of handling **SIGTERM**:

```bash
kill -15 -$process_group_id
# OR
kill -TERM -$process_group_id
# OR
kill -SIGTERM -$process_group_id
```

There is more in [kill: Send a signal to processes](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/kill-invocation.html#kill-invocation) if you are using *GNU coreutils*. If not, maybe `man kill` or `info kill` could help better.